# If else statements and subStrings (new to programming in Java)

Tags: java

So when I run this code, the main menu appears like so

```
1) 1
2) 2
3) 3
```

the numbers in the following order represent Display Journeys, Suitable Journeys and Quit. (Yet to be changed)
My problem is, When I run the code and select option two (latter half of the code) both "Specify Destination and Specify Max Time (HH:MM)) Appear in the console like it's suppose to, but my subString is reading the user input for Destination and not for Max Time causing an Error. 
I need the user to be able to input both Destination and Time.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

```
if (User1 == 1)
{
    System.out.println("You have selected Display Journeys");
    try (BufferedReader ReadFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\input.txt"))) 
    {
           String line = null;
           while ((line = ReadFile.readLine()) != null) 
           {
               System.out.println(line);
           }
    }
}
else if (User1 ==2)
{
    System.out.println("You have selected Suitable Journeys");
    System.out.println("");

    String Destination = S.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Specify :" + Destination);
    System.out.print("");

    System.out.print("Specify Max Time (HH:MM): " );
    String specificTime = S.next();
    String hours = specificTime.substring(0,2);
    String minutes = specificTime.substring(3,5);
    System.out.println(hours + minutes);
}
```

Comment: String specificTime = S.next(); needs to be  String specificTime = S.nextLine();

Comment: you show no effort to figure out what went wrong, we wont to help but show us what you have done and what you think went wrong. Coming here for quick answer (to your ?? homework) is not going to help you learn

Comment: What I think has gone wrong is the sub string is reading the wrong input and I'm entirely sure why. I've spent many hour trying to figure out what wrong before coming here.
Not to mention this isn't homework, it's a hobby I've recently gotten into.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should print the prompt before you accept user input, otherwise you won't know what you are entering. For example, in your code

```
String Destination = S.nextLine();
System.out.println("Specify :" + Destination);
```

That first line will halt and wait for output with no prompt as what to enter.

Changing around a few lines should get you your expected results.

```
System.out.print("Specify Destination: ");
String Destination = S.nextLine();

System.out.print("Specify Max Time (HH:MM): ");
String specificTime = S.nextLine();
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this (or any other answers) have helped you, you can click the checkmark on the left of the answer under the arrows. You are also able to upvote any helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

This line reads up to the next Enter key:

```
String Destination = S.nextLine();
```

So you are reading destination and Max Time at the same time into the string Destination.

You need to enter the destination, press enter, then enter the Max Time.

Answer (score 0):

I suppouse `S` is a `scanner` object.

```
if (User1 == 1)
{
    System.out.println("You have selected Display Journeys");
    try (BufferedReader ReadFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\input.txt"))) 
    {
           String line = null;
           while ((line = ReadFile.readLine()) != null) 
           {
               System.out.println(line);
           }
    }
}
else if (User1 ==2)
{
    System.out.println("You have selected Suitable Journeys");
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Specify Destination:");
    System.out.print("");
    String destination = S.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Specify Max Time (HH:MM): " );
    String specificTime = S.nextLine();
    String hours = specificTime.substring(0,2);
    String minutes = specificTime.substring(3,5);
    System.out.println(hours + minutes);
}
```